# R How to vectorize a filter table lookup

Tags: r, filter, vectorization, tidyr, tibble

I am looking to find a way to vectorize a table lookup. Here is an example of my expected input/output without using a loop.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


input <- tibble(
  value = c(2, 1.5, 3), 
  color = c('blue', 'green', NA)
)
table_lookup <- tibble(
  min = c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5), 
  max = c(1.5, 2.5, 99999), 
  color = c('green', 'blue', NA), 
  output = c(8:10)
 )
## Desired output By filtering "value" from the input between min (excluded min) and max and color match with color from "table_lookup".
c(9, 8, 10)
```

Thank you,

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sapply` along with the `which` function:

```
sapply(input$value, 
       FUN = function(x) table_lookup$output[which(x > table_lookup$min & x <= table_lookup$max)])
```

Another option would be to use `merge` and then `filter`:

```
merge(input, table_lookup, by = NULL) %>%
    filter(value > min, value <= max)

#   value color.x min     max color.y output
# 1   1.5   green 0.5     1.5   green      8
# 2   2.0    blue 1.5     2.5    blue      9
# 3   3.0    <NA> 2.5 99999.0    <NA>     10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
fuzzy_left_join(x = input, 
                y = table_lookup, 
                by = c("value" = "min", "value" = "max"), 
                match_fun = list(`>`, `<=`))

# A tibble: 3 x 6
  value color.x   min     max color.y output
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>    <int>
1   2   blue      1.5     2.5 blue         9
2   1.5 green     0.5     1.5 green        8
3   3   NA        2.5 99999   NA          10
```

Comment: It seems that fuzzy_left_join is pretty slow when it comes to big dataset. Is there a way to improve efficiency ? Thank you